# Can i choose to only upload iPhone version

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad

Is it possible for me to develop a iPhone and iPad application but then only choose to upload the iPhone version?

The reason being is that the client still isn't sure if they want the iPad version but i have developed some of their app already?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just click on the Project -> General

Then select target

And change to
Devices -> iPhone

Here is screenshot
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Just set `iPhone` in your target `Deployment info`. After you build deploy it you just set it back to `Universal`

If you will do it often you should write a rule in your CI (if you're using such a thing). But as you said if more or less single exception rather then rule.

[image]

Here is a screenshot

Answer (score 1):

In project settings just change from "Universal" to "iPhone". It will disable the iPad support.